# Why cant resharper null analysis determine this cannot be null?

Tags: c#, null, resharper, code-analysis

Why does resharper warn that File2 may be null? If File2 is null, then file2Data will be null, therefore it is impossible for the else condition to evaluate.

```
public File File2;
....

var file2Data = File2?.Data;
if (file2Data == null)
{
    CanSaveFile2 = false;
}
else
{
    //File2 -> Warning: Possible Null Reference Exception
    CanSaveFile2 = File2.FileOpen;  
}

public class File{
    public byte[] Data;
}
```

Comment: Possibly because it's a field, and the field could have changed value?

Comment: I'm guessing because you are checking if ```file2Data``` is null, not if ```File2``` is null. Especially with multiple chained null-conditional operators I can see that this could get quite tricky to evaluate (such as: ```a?.b?.c?.value```).

Comment: Another thread could possible change the fields value in between, in particular set it to `null`.

Comment: And what version of Resharper do you use?

Comment: I think @Evk is touching the real issue here. I have ReSharper 2017.3.5 and only if I comment out the if-then-else part (keeping only the block with CanSavefile2 = ...) do I get a warning about nullability issues, so at least on my end it seems ReSharper doesn't flag this as possible null reference exception.

Comment: I have the latest 2018 EAP release

Comment: As commented above, but tying the two comments together, the two checks against `File2?.Data` and `File2.FileOpen` are not within a locked section, so in a multi-threaded application `File2` could be set to null after the first check and before the second check

Comment: Isn't that true of all fields though?